# Angular Service response remembers initial parameter

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Below a simplified version of my call to my Service.

Component:

```
for (let platform of this.platforms) {

    this.artistsService.getFollowers(uuid, platform)
   .subscribe((data: any[]) => { console.log(platform); })
}
```

Service:

```
  getFollowers(uuid: string, platform: string): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get<any[]>(this.baseUrl + '/followers/' + platform + '/' + uuid + '?format=json', httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError('getFollowers', []))
      );
  }
```

I would like the callback to remember the platform which was provided. At this moment I do not know from which platform the data is coming from.

Any ideas how a parameter can be remembered in the response?

Comment: Your missing the issue here. The issue is that `platform` changes because of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping through the `platforms` array using `for` and `subscribe` to each item of it, you can combine them in one `observable` suing `RxJS`'s [from](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/from) function, and then subscribe to it, where you can get every emitted platform and do some logic around it alongside its followers.

Try the following:

```js
from(this.platforms)
  .pipe(
    concatMap((platform) =>
      this.getFollowers(uuid, platform).pipe(
        map((followers) => ({ platform, followers }))
      )
    )
  )
  .subscribe(({ platform, followers }) => {
    // Here you will get each platform and its followers.
    console.log(platform, followers);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`forkJoin`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin) to create a single observable that executes all requests and emits an object where the param is the key and the response is the value:

```js
const platforms = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

const allRequests = platforms.reduce(
  (obj, p) => ({ ...obj, [p]: http(p) })
, {});

const allRequests$ = forkJoin(allRequests);

allRequests$.subscribe(
  responseObj => console.log(responseObj)
);

// Output:
//
//  {
//    one:   "response #one",
//    two:   "response #two",
//    three: "response #three"
//  }
```

Here's a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ko5jvs?devtoolsheight=60) demo.